# Conformination message webform Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

Does anyone know how i can setup conformation emails to be delivered to customers when they fill in the webform/contact us form (details like name;email etc) in drupal 7.

Like when a customer submits a inquiry email an auto responsive email should be forwarded to that customers email.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Content > Webforms > Click on modify on one of your forms > Go to the Webform tab (upper left corner) to where your form fields are listed. Underneath is a second row of tabs, one of which says Email. > Click the Email tab > Add new email and configure.